# What happened to "Too localized"?

Tags: discussion

We used to be able to vote to close or flag questions as "too localized" if they were only relevant to a small region or specific point in time. I've come across a few questions recently that fit that criteria, but we don't seem to have an equivalent in the new wording. Am I missing something? Are we allowing more localized questions now? Is it simply an oversight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant links:

- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/
- [Responding to your "too localized" concerns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns)

Basically, "too localized" was one of the least used and most misused close reasons, so it went away when the close reasons got revamped.

Comment: So how do we handle questions that are clearly too localized. E.g.: Does X brand currently manufacture a y widget? Where in Smalltown, USA can I find a whatever-thing? We get them on a semi-regular basis and they don't seem to fit any other closure criteria. Are we allowing those now?

Comment: @jimirings: I think we should have a separate meta discussion for each of those, get them defined as off-topic, and create appropriate off-topic reasons for them... (maybe one that covers all those things?)

Comment: Fair enough. I'll start it up.